# Making text fade out with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT: I originally had left in an extra closing bracket in the script, which was causing the error. The code as it stands now works as I'd hoped.

I have some text that is displayed in the center of the page when it loads. I would like to have this text fade out (actually fade in and then out, but I'm thinking getting it to fade in will be simple after I figure out how to make it fade out. So, I looked up what I could find and came upon the JQuery fadeOut function, which I've implemented below. For some reason, though, the text still doesn't fade out. What am I doing wrong, and what is the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="backgroundstyle.css">
  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <center><h1 class="titletext" id="text" style="color : darkblue; " ><b>Harness the power of the web</b></h1></center>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#text").fadeOut();
         });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: First thing first, **don't misuse `<br>`**. If you don't know how to use it, don't! Also, `<center>` is obsolete in HTML5, use CSS instead.

Comment: You seem to have an extra `});` at the end; are you sure there isn't just a syntax error preventing your JS from running?

Comment: i think it is working ok check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qrk2aqsL/) from your code. just remove a few lines of code in js

Comment: Try adding a delay or change `.ready` to `.load` because the browser may not be ready to fade? This sometimes happens because the browser has too many things on hand to render.

Comment: use margin or padding to achieve the spacing not 498 <br>'s

Comment: Thanks for the extra hints... and yes it was actually a syntax error. I have forgotten the call to fadeOut was originally inside an onClick method. So what should I do with this question? just make a note in the question that it was a syntax error? Delete it?

Comment: Edit the question and correct.

Answer (score 2):

I removed all unnecessary code for clarity and it now works.

Your mistake was - extra brackets in jQuery code `});`

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#text").fadeOut();
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <center>
      <h1 class="titletext" id="text" style="color : darkblue; " ><b>Harness the power of the web</b></h1></center>
  </body>
  </html>
```

---

Helpful [article](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) from the official website about `fadeOut()`

Answer (score 2):

With bootstrap v3.3.7 that you are using, you need to use `jquery version 1.9.1` or higher but lower than `version 4`. Also you are including `font-awesome css` in `script tag` and that too not in src, use link instead and  Also remove the extra brackets `})` in  `$(document).ready(function(){`

SomeTips:

Instead of using `<br>` so many times unnecessarily you can make use of css attributes. Similary center is absoulte in HTML5 so better you make use of `text-align` css attribute

Also fadeout your text after a certain delay. for that use setTimeout or delay function

**setTimeOut**

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#text").fadeOut("slow");}, 2000)
```

**delay**

```
$("#BodyField").delay(2000).fadeOut();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){$("#text").fadeOut("slow");}, 2000) 
     
  });
```

```css
.titletext {

  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>

  <body class="background">
    
   <h1 class="titletext" id="text" style="color : darkblue; " ><b>Harness the power of the web</b></h1>
    
  </body>
```

If you are having your fadeout function on an onclick event then no need to use setTimeout just take care of the other corrections and have a `"slow"` parameter in fadeout to have a nice transition effect.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn').on('click',function(){
    $("#text").fadeOut("slow");
  })
   
     
  });
```

```css
.titletext {

  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>

  <body class="background">
    <button id="btn" >FadeOut</button>
   <h1 class="titletext" id="text" style="color : darkblue; " ><b>Harness the power of the web</b></h1>
    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#text").fadeOut("slow"); // Or you can mention the duration.
});
```